# Talk to I2C Devices connected to Arduino from Processing

Tags: arduino, processing, i2c

I want to talk to devices that are connected to an Arduino from the Processing IDE and interface with the I2C communications protocol. The processing language is used to send command and data bytes to the arduino with the Firmata protocol. This is done with an existing arduino and Firmata library. I have been going through the library and it seems that there is functionality on both the Arduino and Processing sites to support I2C communication to devices connected to the Arduino, but there is no method to do that from processing. I have tried to create a method to do that but I couldn't get anywhere.

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: You must send info to arduino via serial(example) and arduino interpret it to call to I2C-command. Example: send from processing "123-on" and arduino must call to the adress '123' and send 'on'

Comment: I know that method but I am looking for something that will extend the Arduino processing library. i.e will use Firmata protocol through the serial to communicate to Arduino rather than the serial port on its own
I dont' think there is something out there for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone who might be interested of, I have found a solution to extend Processing Firmata Library to support additional features. 
Based on this tutorial http://www.instructables.com/id/Going-Beyond-StandardFirmata-Adding-New-Device-Sup/ you have to edit Processing Arduino and Firmata Library, which are written in Java. Then compile the two and replace them in the source folder.
Then follow the tutorial to extend the Arduino Firmata Library on the Arduino end.